# Validar fecha de inicio y fecha de fin en php (cakephp)

Tags: cakephp-3.x

estoy haciendo un validador en el model de cakephp  hasta el momento tengo:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){  
    $validator
        ->date('fechainicio')
        ->allowEmpty('fechainicio');

    $validator
        ->date('fechafin')
        ->allowEmpty('fechafin');



    return $validator;
}
```

Tengo la idea de hacer una validación personalizada para que la fecha de fin sea mayor a la fecha de inicio, pero no tengo idea como hacer...alguna idea?

**EDITADO**

estaba pensando hacer algo como esto:

```
 $validator
        ->date('fechafin')
        ->allowEmpty('fechafin')
        ->add(
            'cedula',
            ['validarFechas' => [
                'rule' => 'validarFechas',
                'provider' => 'table',
                'message' => 'Fecha final debe ser mayor a fecha de inicio',]
            ]);
```

Con una función:

```
public function validarFechas($fechainicio,$fechafin) {
   $fechainicio=('fechainicio');
   $fechafin=('fechafin');
   if(strtotime($fechafin) > strtotime($fechainicio)){
       $v=true;
   }
   else{
       $v=false;
   }      
   return $v;
}
```

Pero no funciona...alguna idea??

Comment: Como sugerencia, procura siempre indicar por qué no funciona, qué significa _no funciona_.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente código me funciona para validar que la fecha de finalización sea posterior a la de inicio con CAKE PHP 3.

## Validator

```
   $validator
       ->date('expired')
      ->requirePresence('expired', 'create')
      ->allowEmptyDate('expired', false);

   $validator 
      ->date('fecha_inicio')
      ->requirePresence('fecha_inicio', 'create')
      ->allowEmptyDate('fecha_inicio', false)
      ->add('fecha_inicio',
            [
               'validarFechas'=>
                  [
                     'rule'=>'validarFechas',
                      'provider'=>'table',
                      'message'=>'Fecha Invalida.'
                   ]
             ]
       );
```

## Method

```
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\I18n\Date;

    public function validarFechas($value,$context)
    {
            if (!empty($context['data']['fecha_inicio']) && !empty($context['data']['expired'])) 
            {
                $sd = $context['data']['fecha_inicio'];
                $sd = $sd['year'].'-'.$sd['month'].'-'.$sd['day'];
                $ed = $context['data']['expired'];
                $ed = $ed['year'].'-'.$ed['month'].'-'.$ed['day'];

                $inicio = new Date($sd);
                $fin = new Date($ed);
                if ($inicio < $fin) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false; 

                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre incluir una breve explicación de cómo usar lo que sugieres y cómo arregla el problema que indican.